Testing Combustion Kinetic Mechanisms
The chemical modeling of combustion depends on kinetic mechanisms, that is, intricate networks of chemical reactions that describe the transformation of reactants into products. For a mechanism of $n_r$ elementary reactions involving $n_s$ chemical species, the production rate of a chemical species $\mathcal{S}_j$ involved in the mechanism is expressed as $\mathrm{d}c_j/\mathrm{d}t$, where $c_j$ corresponds to the molar concentration of $\mathcal{S}_j$.
The temporal variation of $c_j$ depends on each rate of the $n_r$ elementary reactions, $\omega_i$, in such a way that
\begin{equation}\label{Eq4}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}c_j}{\mathrm{d}t} = \sum_{i=1}^{n_r} (\nu_{ji}''-\nu_{ji}') \omega_i,
\end{equation}
where $\nu_{ji}'$ and $\nu_{ji}''$ are, respectively, the stoichiometric coefficients of the species $\mathcal{S}_j$ as reactant and product in the $i$-th reaction of the mechanism. Here, $\omega_i$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
    \omega_i = k_{\text{f}i} \prod_{j=1}^{n_s} c_j^{\nu_{ji}'} -  k_{\text{b}i} \prod_{j=1}^{n_s} c_j^{\nu_{ji}''},
\end{equation*}
with $k_{\text{f}i}$ and $k_{\text{b}i}$ representing the specific rates of the $i$-th reaction, forward and reverse, respectively. These rates can be obtained in reaction $i$ through the modified Arrhenius equation
\begin{equation*}
    k_i = A_i T^{\beta_i} e^{-E_i/(RT)},
\end{equation*}
When testing a combustion kinetic mechanism, product concentrations are calculated at different temperatures. To do this, it's necessary to provide the initial concentrations of the fuel and oxidizer, $c_F(t_0)$ and $c_{O_2}(t_0)$, respectively, along with some Arrhenius parameters. My questions are: What is the appropriate choice for the initial concentration $c_F$ and $c_{O_2}$ for testing a kinetic mechanism? Should this concentration remain the same across all temperatures considered?

More appropriate than what? Combustion kinetics can change a lot. BTW it would be rather kinetic model you want of chemical mechanism?

I edited my question to make it clearer. Thank you.
